# Checking more than one character with CharAt()

Tags: java

I am struggling with the charAt method.what i want to know is if when you use charAt, are you able to use more than one number in the parameter, so that you look at more than one character in one method?

Comment: i would suggest adding proper tags to your question <Javascript> so that you will receive help quickly. as per your question, you can loop and concat unless someone can suggest a much easier way using regex.

Comment: Tagging as both "java" and "javascript" is very confusing. They are almost entirely different languages. Are you asking about Java's String.charAt?

Comment: It sounds like you want substring of string. check the String API and you will find a method called subString.

Comment: It would help if you give a hypothetical example of what you would like CharAt to do.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no vanilla JavaScript method for that. You could always write one that prototypes the String object, though:

```
String.prototype.charsAt = function(indexes) {
    var returned = [ ];
    for(var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
    {
        returned.push(this.charAt(indexes[i]));        
    }
    return returned;
}
```

You can then call it using:

```
var text = 'mystring';
alert(text.charsAt([0, 1]));
```

You can see a working demo here > http://jsfiddle.net/MDNRS/. As others have said though, this is really entirely trivial, as you should use `substr()` or other methods.

Comment: This written before the JavaScript tag was removed. Can you confirm if the question relates to Java or JavaScript...

Comment: Leave it even if it is not for Javascript.It may be useful for someone else.It is the OP error for the confusion anyway

Comment: Thanks @Cratylus. I'll leave it here for reference and posterity.

Answer (score 0):

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> charAt
>
> public char charAt(int index)
>
> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() -
>     The first char value of the sequence is at
>   index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.

If you need something else you can use `toCharArray()` to access the underlying `char[]` and do what you need

Answer (score 0):

looks like your understanding of method [charat(int index)](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/lang/string-class-tutorial/charat-method-example/) is a little bit off. Calling this method is simply to get a single character at specified index.

If you are looking for searching a specific character sequence, you might want to look into the [contains(CharSequence cs)](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/lang/string-class-tutorial/contains-method-example/) method of String class.

Reference:

[Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)